# Setting Member Variable from within returned promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, this, q

I have an issue that I feel deals with the idiosyncrasies of javascript.  Basically, I am trying to set a member/class variable to from within a then function of a promise.  For example:

```
 this.intuitAuth.authenticate()
      .then(function(oauthObj){
        this.setOauthObj(oauthObj);

        return oauthObj;
      });
```

Where `this.setOauthObj(oauthObj);` sets the member variable for the outside object.  Now I think maybe my problem is with `this` being the problem since I am thinking `this` refers to the function within the `then` function.  So my question is, how can I set a member variable from within `then` function of a promise? Or is it even possible.

The reason I want to accomplish this is because I would like to have this variable be set from within the object's instance, so I dont have to pass it in to every method call as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A function's **this keyword** behaves a little differently in JavaScript
>   compared to other languages. It also has some differences between
>   [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) and non-strict mode.

There are at least two ways you can solve the problem:

### [Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Assuming *this* as used in `this.intuitAuth` is the desired *this*, then you may bind the function scope to that as follows:

```
this.intuitAuth.authenticate()
    .then(function(oauthObj){
        this.setOauthObj(oauthObj);    
        return oauthObj;
     }.bind(this));
```

### Keep a reference to the desired `this`.

```
var _this = this;
this.intuitAuth.authenticate()
    .then(function(oauthObj){
        _this.setOauthObj(oauthObj);    
        return oauthObj;
     });
```

Now either of those would more than likely solve your current issue. But you need to understand why the problem exists, hence you should read more about [how the value of `this` is set in a scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: "a little differently" :D, although I would argue it is not the best practice to use `var_this = this`. It can get confusing. In this particular case you could just get away with `then(setOauthObj.bind(yourThis));` , no point having return value...

Comment: Personally, I usually go for `var self = this;` or depending on the context something like `var simulator = this;`. But that's not the point at the moment. The issue is not about best practice, but rather about a misunderstanding of the concept. So I'm more interested in getting the message across clearly than in anything else. In any case, the OP has the responsibility to name the variable as s/he finds most convenient. Thanks for your input though, it's worth considering.

Comment: @webduvet, re "no point having return value", if we were to simplify to `.then(this.setOauthObj.bind(yourThis))` (with or without the bind), then we are a hostage to fortune with regard to the return value; we don't know what `this.setOauthObj()` returns and it may not be what is required. Therefore, in the absence of full sight of `.setOauthObj()`, explicitly returning `oauthObj` is necessary.

Comment: @IgweKalu, you need either `var _this = this` or `.bind(this)`, not both.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, you do not assign or call returned value. no need to return anything.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, as I wrote in my answer **"There are at least two ways you can solve the problem"**. Now I wonder how you came to the conclusion that I suggested both. I simply demonstrated both ways. Thanks for sharing your opinion anyway.

Comment: @IgweKalu, in your second solution, `.bind(this)` is unnecessary because `this` in the function has been replaced by `_this`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, ah I see, I copy pasted from previous solution, and forgot to remove that. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I guessed that's what happened - I've done similar many times :-)